# Should I use a Webhook or AWS queue (SQS)?

Tags: node.js, webhooks, amazon-sqs

I've been implementing an SQS service(AWS) for my project. My purpose for this implement is I have 2 projects (microservice) and I want to sync data from one project to another. So, I intend to use SQS service but I also think about webhook for solving my case. I know some basics of the pros and cons of them. So, my question is should I use a webhook or SQS for my case?

Thanks for any helping!

Comment: You need to give a better explanation of what is your requirements and your concerns.

Comment: Hi @RoeeGavirel. The detail of my case is I have a service A which has database A1 and service B which has database B1. I want to sync data from database A1 to database B1 when database A1 has any update. I have a little bit confused between use an SQS and webhook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you wish to sync 2 databases you would probably want something that's not accounting on your service. Try reading about [change data capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) - Log scanners is a safe way to do that. Debezium - is a strong tool for it.

Second, if you wish to go with your own implementation I would suggest going with the queueing approach. The biggest advantage of it will be incased when the second service is down. While if using Webhooks the information will be lost, using queues (SQS or any other) will keep the data until the service is up again.

Comment: I also think about the case of service is down in seconds. It may be the best solution for keeping the data if this case happens. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

SQS is your best bet here. Couple of reasons
- Reliability in case something is down.
- Ability to repopulate other micro-services. For example if you decide to create another microservice and you need to populate data since start, you will probably read everything from service 1 and put it in the queue for the new micro service.
- Scalability - Queues makes your architecture horizontally scalable. Just put machines to do the work while reading it from queues in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I think SQS is the best solution for my case.